# Get commit messages filtered by tags

Tags: git

How can I log the list of dates, tags and commits messages only for specifics tags?

For instance if in the list of commits there are three commits with tags BUG or BUGFIX or NEW_FEATURE I would log these like this :
05/01/2015 - BUGFIX - Fixed error at login
05/03/2015 - NEW_FEATURE - Added profile image
.
.

I need to ignore all others commits.

Comment: A tag can only apply to a single commit.  Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Ok sorry, I think that I could use this way for export a changelog ignoring all other commit messages.
How can then log only some commits specifics for the changelogs?

Comment: It is possible that you and I are using the word *tag* to mean different things.  Perhaps you could add an example to your question of exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is `git log --grep=BUGFIX` what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly, I don't knew that the tags are uniques.
This is the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A) If you are looking specifically for a 'git tag' (ie a tag added to a commit using `git tag ..` command), then you simply need to do this:

```
git log -1 <tag-name>
```

e.g

```
git log -1 NEW_FEATURE
```

Note that a 'git tag' will be associated with exactly one git commit.

B) If you are looking for a 'keyword' in commit log (which is not called 'tag' in git terminology), then (as mentioned by @twalberg), all you need is:

```
git log --grep=NEW_FEATURE
```

This will bring all the commits containing keyword 'NEW_FEATURE' in the commit message. (I have a feeling this is the answer you were looking for.)